# URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ports", ofType: "geojson")!) is nil?

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

The bellow line returns nil when I run the line in the app (thus making the app crash). This line of code comes from mapboxes [example here](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/examples/clustering/) on grouping.

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ports", ofType: "geojson")!)
```

I implemented that this link which they recommend adding: [link](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/files/clustering.zip)
And add it to the project as follows: 
[image]

***What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?***

Comment: It would be a lot simpler to use `let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ports" withExtension: "geojson")!`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this

```
Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ports", ofType: "geojson")!
```

crashes this means you need to check target membership of this file

for tracking

```
if let file = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ports", ofType: "geojson") {
     let url = URL(fileURLWithPath:file)
}
else { 
    print("Not exists")
}
```

so select the file and tick

[image]